# Limit number of consecutively hyphenated lines to a hard numerical value

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Is there a way to limit the number of consecutive hyphenated lines to a fixed maximum value (say, *at most* 3 consecutive lines with hyphen) in (1) LaTeX *and* (2) LuaLaTeX?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\textwidth=22mm\relax
\begin{document}
\noindent
Der vom Bundestagsbeauftragten beauftragte Bundesdatenschutzbeauftragte
\end{document}
```

Output using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) with dvi output:

[image: excerpt from the resulting dvi output using pdftex]

I am aware that by adjusting `\doublehyphendemerits` and `\emergencystretch` i can avoid too many hyphens, but as i understood, those parameters only reduce the *probability* of two (or more) consecutive hyphenated lines. Is there a way to give (Lua)LaTeX a hard, *numerical*, upper limit?

Comment: In legacy TeX no, maybe with LuaTeX. On the other hand, a high value of `\doublehyphendemerits` will make demerits blow up with four or more consecutive hyphens, so they would only be used if really no other solution is possible.

Comment: @egreg I read that penalties and demerits are capped at 10000, which is the default value for `\doublehyphendemerits`, according to `latex.ltx`. As I understood, any value higher than that has no effect. So, I tried `\doublehyphendemerits=500000`, and as expected, that doesn't make any difference in the MWE (on its own).

Comment: No, demerits are not capped. Penalties are, but they contribute to the total demerits, via badness of lines. Your example is not really a good test, because of the very narrow line width that makes impossible even to typeset the paragraph without overfull boxes.

Comment: Why doesn't tex resolve to underfull lines or stretching spacecs beyond emergencystretch? At some point those must be less costly than added-up penalties from `\doublehyphendemerits` violations? And  shouldn't even overfull boxes become acceptable at some point when hyphens get "too expensive"?

Comment: Besides, the 3 was only one example; what if a publisher wants at most 4, 5, or even only 2 consecutive hyphenations?

Comment: If I set `\emergencystretch` to a large value I get a horribly typeset paragraph, but with only two consecutive hyphens. You aren't setting `\emergencystretch`, so it's not used.